# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `ResetOnRespawn' to `ResetOnRespawn[]' c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please how to fix this error

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `ResetOnRespawn` to `ResetOnRespawn[]`

[image]

Comment: Please past the actual code, not an image

Comment: Grab an element out of the array, or convert your single item to an array (depending on use case). Looks like the latter from your image, but its hard to tell because its an image.

Comment: it should work:  `ObjectToReset[yourindexhere]= FindObjectOfType<ResetOnRespawn>();`

Comment: I can not post a full code
 Give me this error

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon

Comment: @WEBPROGRAMMING and what about it did you not understand? simply add your code, select it all and click the `{ }` button this adds the indentation for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either meant [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) <- mind the '*s*'

or following your variable names it should be simply only one instead of an array:

```
public ResetOnRespawn ObjectToReset;
```